# git public issue - ubuntu users

Tags: git, ubuntu, permissions, github, pull

I have 2 users for my server call them superuser and editor

superuser has access to everything can sudo etc. When I try and pull from github I get Permission denied (publickey).

Now when I chown all the files to editor I can pull the files unless they were created by 'superuser', the question is how do I add 'superuser' so they can pull from gitgub

Answer (score 0):

Simply make them part of a group and give the files read-write permissions to the group.